# Detection a two different math cases using c#

Tags: c#

I have this code that should run "Amount" times. The code has to do a math equation called
[collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#:%7E:text=The%20Collatz%20conjecture%20is%20one,every%20positive%20integer%20into%201.), how it works is you get a number, if its odd you have to * by 3 and than add 1 but if its even you have to divide it by 2, this should go on until the number hits one, if the number does it one the variable Ver should be added but one otherwise this should get in a never ending loop, The problem is I don't know how to detect that loop. The code bellow is the whole thing without the loop detection and when I run it 1 million times it worked fine expect 432 numbers specifically that should not get in that loop.

The problem is you never know if the math equation is still happening or is it a special case that will never hit the number 1.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

int Amount = 1000000;
int Ver = 0;
Amount++;
for (int i = 1; i < Amount; i++)
{
    int i2 = i;
    while (i2 > 1)
    { 
        if (i2 % 2 == 0) {
            int i3 = i2 / 2;
            i2 = i3;
        }
        else
        {
            i2 = (i2 * 3) + 1;
        }
    }
    if (i2 == 1 || i2==4 || i2==2)
    Ver++;
}
Amount--;
Console.WriteLine(Ver + " of "+ Amount + " numbers were verified.");
```

> A good idea would be if the program was stuck on number for too long (More than 2 or 3 minuets) to Maybe ask in the console to see if the program should continue on a number or should it skip that number. I have tried putting on timer each time it gets to a new number but it will slow the program  by almost 3 or 4 times. Does anyone know a faster way to do that?

Comment: It sounds to me that if `i2` reaches a value it has had before, you'd know that you are stuck in a loop?

Comment: @Astrid E Thank you for your comment. I'm not really looking for the loop, my goal is to see if am I ever going to hit a loop for not  because as you see here I do know how to find the loop `if (i2 == 1)` because the loop only happens if `i2` hits 1 so this code itself can find the loop.

Comment: My bad, I must have misunderstood your question. I thought you wanted to detect that you had _reached_ a never-ending loop. Is it correct that you rather want to _foresee_  (for a starting number `x`) that you _will_ hit a never-ending loop at some point?

Comment: I'm sorry, I shouldn't have used the work loop because it makes it confusing. From never-ending-loop I mean random number that will never lead to one or lead to negative numbers.

Comment: A good idea would be if the program was stuck on number for too long (More than 2 or 3 minuets) to Maybe ask in the console to see if the program should continue on a number or should it skip that number. I have tried putting on timer each time it gets to a new number but it will slow the program  by almost 3 or 4 times. Does anyone know a faster way to do that?

Comment: If you want to know ahead of time that an input will never hit "1", you'd need to mathematically prove that there is a method to foresee that. What you _can_ do more easily is introduce a cap point. For example you say "it is pretty safe to say, it will not converge after 1000000 iterations" (I don't know if that's reasonable, you'll have to find that value out). Then you can extend the loop condition to "stop if it hit 1 OR looped for more than N times". You then need to distinguish between those cases, of course.

Comment: You can detect loops with the Floyd’s Cycle Detection Algorithm. But the question is why you do have loops where you should not. Spoiler it's because of integer overflow : you work with value greater than Int.Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution does not pretend to be academic.

Due to [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20many%20numbers%20have%20been%20checked%20for%20collatz%20conjecture&rlz=1C1UEAD_enAU1028AU1028&oq=how%20many%20numbers%20have%20been%20checked%20for%20collatz%20conjecture&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160l2.1557j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) you provided you must use ulong (UInt64) at least instead of int (Int32)

You can use [TPL DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) with CancellationToken:

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

const ulong start = 20_000_001;
const ulong amount = 10_000_000;
const ulong maxIterations = 1000_0000;

ulong verified = 0;
ConcurrentBag<ulong> canceledNumbers = new ConcurrentBag<ulong>();
ConcurrentBag<ulong> overflowNumbers = new ConcurrentBag<ulong>();

var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<ulong>(CollatzAction,
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2, // Remove 2 if you don't have hyperthreading
        BoundedCapacity = Environment.ProcessorCount * 4, // Back pressure to avoid the memory overhead
    });

for (ulong i = start; i < start + amount; i++)
{
    await actionBlock.SendAsync(i).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

actionBlock.Complete();
await actionBlock.Completion.ConfigureAwait(false);

Console.WriteLine($"{verified} of {amount} numbers were verified, {canceledNumbers.Count} were canceled.");

if (!canceledNumbers.IsEmpty)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Canceled numbers are: {string.Join(", ", canceledNumbers)}");
}

if (!overflowNumbers.IsEmpty)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Overflow numbers are: {string.Join(", ", overflowNumbers)}");
}

void CollatzAction(ulong i)
{
    try
    {
        var (oneIsReached, isCanceled) = Collatz(i);

        if (oneIsReached)
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref verified);
        }
        else if (isCanceled)
        {
            canceledNumbers.Add(i);
        }
    }
    catch (OverflowException)
    {
        overflowNumbers.Add(i);
    }
}

(bool oneIsReached, bool isCanceled) Collatz(ulong i)
{
    ulong iteration = 1;

    while (i > 1 && iteration <= maxIterations)
    {
        i = (i & 1) == 0 // the same as i % 2 == 0 but faster
            ? i / 2
            : checked(i * 3 + 1);

        iteration++;
    }

    return (i == 1, iteration > maxIterations);
}
```

You can try to replace ulong with BigInteger to avoid overflows, but it's much slower:

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

BigInteger start = 100_000_001;
const ulong amount = 10_000_000;
const ulong maxIterations = 1000_0000;

ulong verified = 0;
ConcurrentBag<BigInteger> canceledNumbers = new ConcurrentBag<BigInteger>();

var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<BigInteger>(CollatzAction,
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2, // Remove 2 if you don't have hyperthreading
        BoundedCapacity = Environment.ProcessorCount * 4, // Back pressure to avoid the memory overhead
    });

for (BigInteger i = start; i < start + amount; i++)
{
    await actionBlock.SendAsync(i).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

actionBlock.Complete();
await actionBlock.Completion.ConfigureAwait(false);

Console.WriteLine($"{verified} of {amount} numbers were verified, {canceledNumbers.Count} were canceled.");

if (!canceledNumbers.IsEmpty)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Canceled numbers are: {string.Join(", ", canceledNumbers)}");
}

void CollatzAction(BigInteger i)
{
    var (oneIsReached, isCanceled) = Collatz(i);

    if (oneIsReached)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref verified);
    }
    else if (isCanceled)
    {
        canceledNumbers.Add(i);
    }
}

(bool oneIsReached, bool isCanceled) Collatz(BigInteger i)
{
    ulong iteration = 1;

    while (i > 1 && iteration <= maxIterations)
    {
        i = (i & 1) == 0 // the same as i % 2 == 0 but faster
            ? i / 2
            : i * 3 + 1;

        iteration++;
    }

    return (i == 1, iteration > maxIterations);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, everything worked well but it outputted `9806116 of 10000000 numbers were verified` which is not possible because I have done some research and I know for a fact that the first 1 quintillion numbers verified according to this [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+many+numbers+have+been+checked+for+collatz+conjecture&rlz=1C1UEAD_enAU1028AU1028&oq=how+many+numbers+have+been+checked+for+collatz+conjecture&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160l2.1557j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @kevinjonson133 try with datatype `long` instead of `int` - intermediate values may overflow leading to a false-positive for "infinite loop"

Comment: @Hans Keﬆing do I do that with all variables or only the output?

Comment: @kevinjonson133 the `i2` variable that you use to hold intermediate values. If you just cast the output to `long` any overflow already happened

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Fixed the solution to check the oveflow.

Comment: @Yevhen Cherkes Lately I have realized that your code does not let me go past the number 2_900_000_000 and it will give the error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'uint' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)` please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: @kevinjonson133 Can you try the latest version of source code? Because I can't reproduce your issue - all works with parameter ulong start = 2_900_000_000;

Comment: @Yevhen Cherkes the number 2_900_000_000 is over the c# integer limit which means the data type should be changed to `uint` or `ulong` but many functions you used to do this only applies to integers. Another problem is many other variables will go past the integer limit meaning the whole code has to be changed.

Comment: also this is what im trying to run: `int start = 1;
uint amount = 2_900_000_000;`

Comment: @kevinjonson133 Yup, please take a look at the latest code in the answer. I replaced int with ulong everywhere

Comment: @Yevhen Cherkes, Thank you so much for all the effort you put in the question. Everything worked as expected.